# Как создать HOC?

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент который создаёт список. Суть в том, что надо из этого компонента сделать переиспользуемый шаблон из которого бы можно было сделать два компонента. 
Один компонент вот этот вот, он берёт данные из .json файла. Второй компонент должен делать всё тоже самое, просто туда передавался бы другой список вместо "films". Как реализовать из этого HOC чтобы не переписывать один и тот же код два раза ?

```js
const FilmList = ({
   films, limit, bookmarkedItems, onAddBookmark 
}) => {

  const filmItem = films
    .slice(0, limit)
    .map((item) => {
      const { title } = item;

    return (
      <li key={ title } className="list-group-item">
        <FilmListItem 
          title={title}
          onAddBookMark={() => onAddBookmark(title)} 
          bookmarked={ bookmarkedItems }
        />
      </li>
    )
  });

  return (
    <ul className="list-group film-list">
      { filmItem }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

То как я возвращаю это в самом контейнере.

```js
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Tabs>
          <div label="Фильмы">
            <SearchPanel 
              onSearchChange={ this.onSearchChange }
              refreshLimit={ this.refreshLimit } 
            />
            <TagPanel 
              tags={ tags }
              selectedTags={ selectedTags }
              onTagSelect={ this.onTagSelect }
            />
            <FilmList 
              films={ filteredList }
              limit={ limit }
              bookmarkedItems={ bookmarks }
              onAddBookmark={ this.onAddBookmark }
            />
            { showButton ? (
              <ShowMoreButton showMore={ this.showMore }/>
            ) : (
              null
            )}  
          </div>
          <div label="Закладки">
           //здесь должен быть этот дублирующийся список
          </div>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
```

Есть такой нюанс, что в компоненте FilmList на вывод я отправляю массив из объектов, который имеет определенную структуру из разряда :

```js
const films = [
{title: film1},
{title: film2},
// и т.д.
]
```

Во втором же случае я вывожу данные из state в которые я записываю данные из LocalStorage. они там хранятся просто как массив из названий фильмов типа как :

```js
const bookmarks = [ film1, film2, film3 ]
```

UPDATE: можно сформулировать вопрос тогда и по другому: Можно ли поставить условие внутри компонента на то, какой именно props туда приходит и в зависимости от этого писать там разный код ?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы тут не нужен HOC?

```
function FilmList2(props) {
  return <FilmList {...props} films={[]} />
}
```

Comment: этот код нужно писать в том месте где я рендерю всё ? или внутри самого компонента ? Просто не совсем понятно как это вызывать потом снаружи

Comment: Это - компонент.

Comment: а как тогда вызвать эту функцию в контейнере в котором я всё рендерю ? У меня просто написаны табы и там react.child не может быть функцией.

Comment: `<FilmList2  limit={10} bookmarkedItems={[]} onAddBookmark={()=>0}  />`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filmItem = films
    .slice(0, limit)
    .map((item) => {
      const { title } = item;

    if ( title !== undefined ) {
      return (
        <li key={ title } className="list-group-item">
          <FilmListItem 
            title={title}
            onAddBookMark={() => onAddBookmark(title)} 
            bookmarked={ bookmarkedItems }
          />
        </li>
      ) 
    } else {
      return (
        <li key={ item } className="list-group-item">
          <FilmListItem 
            title={item}
            onAddBookMark={() => onAddBookmark(item)} 
            bookmarked={ bookmarkedItems }
          />
        </li>
      )
    }
```

решил таким образом. Добавил проверку на входящий props. Если он undefined - как это в случае со вторым списком - тогда добавляй внутрь другие Item. Если есть вариант более элегантный, то буду рад.